# Teams app is in AppSource but not in Teams store

Tags: microsoft-teams

We went through successful publishing process with Zendesk app for Microsoft Teams. It was scheduled to be available in AppSource today, and it is there, however we can't see/find the app directly from Teams app store. Will it appear there later, when to expect it there or we should additionally do something? No warnings were in Partner center, and we got confirmation from TeamsAppSubmission team.

Comment: Already sent an email to them too. Here is the link to AppSource, when I press get it it says App isn't available in Teams... https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200003782?tab=Overview

Comment: Fixed, app is available now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a customer support question, and not about programming.